# Connection string for C# ASP.NET for SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I was wondering if are you able to have two connection strings for two different databases from one SQL Server in one page, for ASP.NET, using C# and Visual Studio.

Any advise would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Yes. What is your actual problem?

Comment: I seem to have an issue when connecting two connection strings, I just duplicate the same code and paste it, then I do the same thing for con.Open/con.Close and commands in between them. But it seems to give an error for one of the user as it tries to login into it.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Password invalid for one of the users databases. The password is correct 100%

Comment: have you tried actually testing the connection and password with sql server manager? (if allowed to login)

Comment: Yes I did and it worked fine for both of them.

Comment: think we need some code samples imo

Comment: sure, I will post it shortly

Comment: Post your code , are you using same sql command and connection object for both ?

Comment: I found the issue, in my connection string for config file, I had   Catalog=  
 set to the same username, after I changed it to the other username it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, is the answer of course you can. Just put both connection strings in the respective config files and switch on them as appropriate. If i was you i would perhaps write some kind of helper class that just allows you to pass in the connection string name. Or you could just use the standard ConfigurationManager API to interact with the config files that way.

But without anything more specific in terms of code samples that's about all the advice i can offer up.